# Hamburger menu and app bar

Tags: layout, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to achieve layout simmilar to Groove application, where hamburger menu is on the left and appbar on the bottom. However, not all pages contains appbar.

I have an usercontrol called MainFrame which contains the hamburger menu and a navigation frame.

**When page is loaded into the navigation frame, the AppBar overlays the HamburgerMenu**. I could just offset the HamburgerMenu, but not all pages contains the AppBar, or the AppBar's height is different.

Is it possible to show the hamburger on top of appbar? Or do you have any other ideas?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you set the `AppBar` in the `SplitView.Content`?

Comment: First of all, I'm using HamburgerMenu control from uwp toolkit. Second, only page has property Page.BottomAppBar. How can I set it in SplitView.Content? When SplitView.Content is Page, the Page.BottomAppBar takes full window width even when the page is narrower

Comment: use [`CommandBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) instead of `Page.BottomAppBar`. Set this in the content Grid of `HamburgerMenu` Like `<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"><Frame/><CommandBar/></Grid>`

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44909437/7331395) solution works then consider Mark as Answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`CommandBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) instead of `Page.BottomAppBar`. Also, it is the recommended way for UWP by Microsoft.

> You should use the AppBar only when you are upgrading a Universal
>   Windows 8 app that uses the AppBar, and need to minimize changes. For
>   new apps in Windows 10, we recommend using the CommandBar control
>   instead.

2. Set the `CommandBar` in the content `Grid` of [`HamburgerMenu`](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/HamburgerMenu/)

Here is a sample code:

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu>
    <!--  Items  -->
    <controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
    <!--  Options  -->
    <controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu.OptionsItemsSource>
    <!--  Content  -->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
        <Frame Name="MainFrame"/>
        <CommandBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</controls:HamburgerMenu>
```